# constant updates/scheduling android

Tags: android

I have seen apps such as sports apps with the upcoming schedules for their teams.

I would like to incorporate this with my app. Currently, I have an upcoming events calendar (.html) that I automatically push with webview. Well, the downside of this is that I have to edit and remove the events when they expire. This takes so much time and I do not have time to do this on a daily basis. I was wondering if it is possible to have them removed after the event expires. If an event ends at 11:00 AM, I would like that to be gone by 11:05 or close to that time. How can this be done?

I come to the plate with little to zero experience with java.
I am learning java with the android development page, so if you say do this... I will most likely not know what you are referring to unless it is explained in details.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Can you access event data without HTML? Perhaps using a web service?

Comment: Tyler, I am unsure of your question. I do not believe we have a web service. How would I know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do in this case is push the events calendar as plain data to your app (as opposed to cooked HTML), and let the app manage how to display it (which might even be with HTML).

If you have the schedule as plain data, you can handle it in the app in a way that makes sense (for example, remove the past events). That also gives you the opportunity to further format the display to make it more useful for the user.

If your calendar changes often and you want to push the changes to your users without having to poll your server, you can (and should) use C2DM: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: this is a lame question...but instead of installing it on a server...could I use a computer?

Comment: if you have an android device, please try to view carolina hurricanes companion and you will see the upcoming schedule. if you could, could you please tell me if that is C2DM? I do not think it is because it is not asking for permission. I do not want to go into that much detail because I do not want to send SMS to users.

Comment: I think they are using a .csv file...but I do not know how to incorporate that with my app.